# Event driven web applications in Java?

Tags: java, jdbc, event-handling

Is it correct to assume that event driven web applications are currently not practical in Java, or is there a framework or techniques that make this practical in java.

It seems to me that it is not possible, but maybe I am missing something.

- JDBC drivers (and JDBC itself) assume thread based/blocking interactions.
- Jetty/Tomcat and other app servers assume Servlets block until the results are ready.

I know Cassandra has "execAsync()" modes, which is promising, but over all it seems like an uphill (impractical) proposition.

Comment: Most Java web application frameworks are built on Servlets which operate a single thread model for handling requests. They are already not well suited for event driven models. Servlet 3.0 does offer asynchronous processing though so there's that.

Comment: Yep, even the servlet specification itself is against the event driven model.

Comment: Also, event driven is usually implemented with function callbacks and Java doesn't really do that. I think the _async_ path is the closest alternative.

Answer (score 1):

This question is very similar to: [Nonblocking io webserver/framework for java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235609/nonblocking-io-webserver-framework-for-java)

Some options are:

- [Grizzly](https://grizzly.java.net/)
- [Deft](http://deftserver.appspot.com/)

These solutions are based off the NIO functionality add in Java 1.4

Comment: Please give a brief overview of the links you posted.

Comment: Neither Deft or its google groups page has not had a real commit or comment for a few years now. Although grizzly looks interesting.